# My code returns an empty list how can I fix it?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I try to get data from website with beautifulsoup module but it returns empty list but I don't want to make with selenium, is it possible? I just want work with beautifulsoup module. I'm working on MacOS.

**My code is:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://data.ibb.gov.tr/dataset/saatlik-trafik-yogunluk-veri-seti/resource/93f996f1-70da-4500-951a-693c7e7066f6/view/9a2a6a74-c7f5-4e2d-96d5-21a57ef7a889")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html")
result = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"recline-slickgrid slickgrid_284950 ui-widget"})
print(result)
```

Comment: You may not want to use Selenium but if the page is built dynamically with JS then BS4 won't be able to find it.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter what is your recommend?

Comment: I can tell by inspecting the page that it's built dynamically so you will need to use something like `Selenium` that accesses the page through a webdriver and wait's for the page to be built. [Here's](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/guide-scraping-dynamic-web-pages-python-selenium) a good resource on `Selenium`

Answer (score 1):

You're in luck. When visiting this specific page, your browser makes an HTTP POST request to a REST API, which returns JSON containing the actual data in the table. Normally, this data is then used to populate the DOM asynchronously using JavaScript. If you imitate that request, you don't need to use `Selenium`, or some other headless browser. you don't even need `BeautifulSoup`, just `requests`.

```
def main():

    import requests

    url = "https://data.ibb.gov.tr/api/3/action/datastore_search"

    data = {
        "resource_id": "93f996f1-70da-4500-951a-693c7e7066f6",
        "filters": {},
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0
    }

    response = requests.post(url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()

    for record in response.json()["result"]["records"]:
        print(f"Latitude: {record['LATITUDE']}, Longitude: {record['LONGITUDE']}")

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
Latitude: 41.0202026367188, Longitude: 28.9105224609375
Latitude: 41.0531616210938, Longitude: 28.6248779296875
Latitude: 41.1849975585938, Longitude: 28.8226318359375
Latitude: 41.0476684570312, Longitude: 28.8665771484375
Latitude: 41.0476684570312, Longitude: 29.1522216796875
Latitude: 40.8828735351562, Longitude: 29.3170166015625
Latitude: 41.1520385742188, Longitude: 28.7896728515625
Latitude: 40.8828735351562, Longitude: 29.3719482421875
Latitude: 40.9927368164062, Longitude: 28.9215087890625
Latitude: 41.0806274414062, Longitude: 28.9215087890625
>>>
```

In this code, each `record` corresponds to one dictionary, which has various key-value pairs. Beyond latitude and longitude, the other columns in the table are available, such as average speed, date and time, etc.

You can change the `"limit": 10` key-value pair in the `data` payload dictionary to whatever value you want. In this case, I only wanted the first ten entries.

In general, though, if you are trying to scrape information from a page which is populated asynchronously using JavaScript, and it does NOT expose a simple REST API, then `BeautifulSoup` nor `requests` will help you. In such a case, you will need a headless browser like `Selenium` or `Playwright` to simulate a full browsing session.

Comment: its working. thank you but I'm new in programming, what does url link and resource_id mean, how did you find this link and resource_id?

Comment: @muratgulcan I found the API URL by opening my browser's dev tool window, and logging all network traffic once I visit the page. I saw that this request was a POST request, and what payload was submitted via POST by my browser - this payload is the `data` dictionary.